# ImageView высота не совпадает с картинкой

Tags: android, xml, android-sdk

Имеется ImageView, в котором есть картинка, но сам этот элемент очень высок и не совпадает с размером картинки, как выровнять эти элементы?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    tools:context=".ChooseMenu">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/clothes"
                    android:src="@drawable/clothes"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="50dp"
                    android:text="ABCD"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/food"
                    android:src="@drawable/food"
                    />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот настолько больше

Comment: Я прочитал вопрос 3 раза, но так и не понял что именно надо выровнять - изображение в ImageView или ImageView в контейнере и как именно выровнять и относительно чего. Попробуйте переформулировать стоящую перед вами задачу.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб картинку в ImageView, только когда задал высоту 150dp и тогда стало адекватней, это нормальный способ?

Comment: Всё зависит от конкретной задачи. Т.к. я так и не понял в чём она состоит, то могу лишь навести на аттрибут `ImageView` `scaleType` - возможно он вам как-то поможет.

Comment: А сами картинки правильно обрезаны? `wrap_content` подразумевает, что отображение по размеру содержимого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте к `ImageView` добавить такой атрибут:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```